# How does one, from a checkbox group and preferably with jQuery, collect array data and does assign this data to a hidden target element's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, collections

I have a group of equally named checkboxes ...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" checked />
```

and a hidden form element ...

```
<input type="hidden" class="target" name="target[]" value="" />
```

Using jQuery, I want to copy all checked checkbox values in form of a value-list in its stringified array literal notation to the hidden target element's value.

I have tried the following ...

```
$(".checkbox").each(function(idx, val) {

  $('input[name="target['+idx+']"]').val(this.value);
});
```

... without success. How can I generate and assign the correct result?

Comment: One or all checkboxes ?

Comment: how do you want to have the `value` attribute of `<input type="hidden" class="target" name="target[]" value="">` be written? As `"1,2,3"` or `"1 2 3"`, even `"[1,2,3]"`, or ..?

Comment: @dm_tr ... i suppose/guess the OP wants to have a somehow ***combined result of all checked checkboxes*** written to the target-input's value.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I want to insert `"[1,2,3]"` as an array to target[] input.

Comment: @user2726957 ... if there are no open questions you might consider voting on answers and accepting the one which was most helpful.

Comment: Two good answers, but you still at this date didn't engaged in additional comments neither accepted any of the provided ones. Why?

Answer (score 1):

basic jQuery approach which does the following ...

1. Query all equally named ... `[name="checkbox[]"]` ... and also `:checked` checkboxes,
2. and convert the resulting jQuery collection into a native array ... `toArray()`.
3. Make use of an array's native [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in order to return an array of (checked) checkbox values,
4. which immediately after gets converted via [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) into its string representation (of an array literal notation),
5. and assigned to the hidden target element's (via jQuery `$('input[name="target[]"]')[0]`) value.

   ```js
   $('input[name="target[]"]')[0].value = JSON.stringify(

     $('[type="checkbox"][name="checkbox[]"]:checked')
       .toArray()
       .map(elm => elm.value)
   );

   console.log(
     'target[] :: value :',
     $('input[name="target[]"]')[0].value
   );
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" checked />
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" checked />

   <input type="hidden" class="target" name="target[]" value="">
   ```

a jQuery free variant of the above approach with checkbox change event handling ...

```js
function updateCheckboxTargetValue() {
  document
    .querySelector('input[name="target[]"]')
    .value = JSON.stringify([
      ...document
        .querySelectorAll(
          '[type="checkbox"][name="checkbox[]"]:checked'
        )
      ].map(elm => elm.value)
    );

  console.log(
    'target[] :: value :',
    document.querySelector('input[name="target[]"]').value
  );
}

function handleCheckboxChange(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches('[type="checkbox"][name="checkbox[]"]')) {

    updateCheckboxTargetValue();
  }
}
updateCheckboxTargetValue();

document.addEventListener('change', handleCheckboxChange);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" checked />

<input type="hidden" class="target" name="target[]" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

map() the `:checked` checkboxes to create array of their values, then stringify that array

```js
const checkedVals = $(".checkbox:checked").map((i,el) => el.value).get()

$('input[name="target[]"]').val(JSON.stringify(checkedVals))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" checked />

<input  class="target" name="target[]" value="">
```

Comment: I like that one for the consistent usage of jQuery's toolchain; I was not even aware anymore (feels like centuries ago) of jQuery's `get()`.